# postman showing 401 forbidden when testing spring security using email and pasword

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have rest end point config as in my application.properties as:

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api/v1
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=secret
security.user.role=USER,ADMIN
```

And since,we implement spring security in pom.xml,we get the default login screen and when i enter username and password in that box,then i get authenticated:

[image]

The login happens successfully.But,when I try from postman,then I got 401 unathorized on response:

My rest endpoints to check is:

```
@RestController
public class BasicAuthController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/basicauth")
    public AuthenticationBean basicauth() {
        System.out.println("hitted here");
        return new AuthenticationBean("You are authenticated");
    }
}
```

So,i tried same username and password from postman and debugging using this **System.out.println("hitted here");** doesnot get print on my console when send from postman.

[image]

I am getting 401 unauthorized while using postman.Even my restend point    `@GetMapping(path = "/basicauth")` is not called.

My websecutry config is:

```
package in.ashwin.onlinebookstore.config;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
 
 
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
 
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
         .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
         .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http         
         .headers()
          .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
          .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/webjars/**","/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
              
    }
 
}
```

Customuserdetailservice is:

```
package in.ashwin.onlinebookstore.config;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import in.ashwin.onlinebookstore.entity.User;
import in.ashwin.onlinebookstore.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(userName)
       .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Email " + userName + " not found"));
         return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(),
         getAuthorities(user));
    }

    private static Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
        String[] userRoles = user.getRoles().stream().map((role) -> role.getName()).toArray(String[]::new);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(userRoles);
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

AuthenticationBean.java

```
public class AuthenticationBean {

    private String message;

    public AuthenticationBean(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I have basic user,role and user_role tables .As user can have many roles.

What is the mistake I did while sending from postman?

Comment: You need to configure Spring Security **WebSecurityConfig** class : .`anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()`

Comment: Is it your intention to use `POST` method?

Comment: oh yes thank you it was get method and it worked fine .

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong data.

You need to put username and password set in the application.properties in the postman basic auth.

```
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=secret
```